# How do I add a column with a repeating series of values to a dataframe such that each member of list is repeated before the next memeber?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I will like to create a column in a dataframe named continent to my existing dataframe df
such that the output has each member of my list 7 time before going to the next member

I tried this

```
import numpy as np
frames = []
for file in files:
    df=wrangle(file)
    frames.append(df)
    continent = ["Central and South America", "Eurasia", "Africa", "Asia Pacific", "Europe", "Middle East", "North America"]
    arr = np.repeat(continent, len(df) // len(continent))
    #arr = np.concatenate([([x]) for x in continent], axis=0) 
    df['continent'] = pd.Series(arr, index=df.index[:len(arr)])
    
df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
print(df.info())
```

i got this

```
Year    Coal    Oil Natural gas Other   MT CO2  continent
0   1990    58  422 104 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
1   1995    62  501 125 NaN MT CO2  Eurasia
2   2000    79  577 171 NaN MT CO2  Africa
3   2005    80  614 218 NaN MT CO2  Asia Pacific
4   2010    99  723 270 NaN MT CO2  Europe
5   2015    132 777 305 NaN MT CO2  Middle East
6   2017    125 734 289 NaN MT CO2  North America
7   1990    899 777 1026    NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
8   1995    603 426 856 14.0    MT CO2  Eurasia
```

But i want the output to be like this

```
Year    Coal    Oil Natural gas Other   MT CO2  continent
0   1990    58  422 104 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
1   1995    62  501 125 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
2   2000    79  577 171 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
3   2005    80  614 218 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
4   2010    99  723 270 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
5   2015    132 777 305 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
6   2017    125 734 289 NaN MT CO2  Central and South America
7   1990    899 777 1026    NaN MT CO2  Eurasisa
8   1995    603 426 856 14.0    MT CO2  Eurasia.......
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your list of continents repeating each element required number of times before creating a new column out of the list.

```
continent = [
    c for c in continent
    for _ in range(7)
]

df['continent'] = continent
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Looks great! :)